# Установка Arch, почти нет утилит (неправильная установка?), нет драйвера для wifi

Tags: wifi, драйвер, установка, kernel, archlinux

машина почти со всем интеловским:

- cpu: 7100u
- интеловский ssd
- wifi адаптер: [такой вот](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/ru/ru/ark/products/94150/intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-8265.html)

**Основные проблемы**:

**1**. Очень мало утилит, только уж совсем базовые *(субъективно)* вроде `ls`, `cd`, `ip link`.

**2**. `ip link` выдаёт только `eth0` и `lo`.

**Мои соображения**:

Первое, на что грешу - нет подключения к сети, отсюда все беды.

*Вы скажете: -"нет у тебя wifi, ок, но почему бы не заюзать `eth0`?"*

Проприетарный разъём Lenovo OneLikn+ позволяет получить доступ к сетевухе `eth0`. Переходник стоит 4 тысячи, пока не хочу его покупать.

Второе, драйвер (модуль ядра?) поставляется как .ucode, называется iwlwifi. Не нашёл способа установить. Вроде как мы можем закинуть его в папку frimware где-то там, перезагрузить комп, и магическим образом iwlwifi появится в списке модулей, но дело в том, что Arch на флешке, значит после перезгрузки он положит на изменения(?). Короче говоря, не получилось.

*Возможно действительно получится установить на ссд, закинуть, перезагрузить и так далее, но мне стало интересно попробовать скомпилировать ядро с этим модулем.*

*События последних 30-и минут:* Не смог найти сурс Arch линуксового ядра, очень напрягает отсутствие утилит, которые используют на Arch Wiki.

Вот, что появляется после выбора установки Arch: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Arch Linux — дистрибутив старой школы, надо самому всё делать, кроме компиляции и сборки пакетов. Именно этим он и интересен. А судя по вопросам, особенно про .ucode, вам рановато пока, хотя, если хотите по-настоящему узнать как работает Unix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: для записи установочного образа использовать USBWrinter(https://sourceforge.net/projects/usbwriter/).

Comment: Какое это имеет отношение к вопросам?

Comment: Это решение той ситуации, которая у меня сложилась в то время. Иначе говоря, проблема заключалась в том, что я плохо записал арч. Для записи образов лучше всего использовать dd конечно

Comment: Ну если уж вдаваться в подробности, то Rufus пока что лучшее компромиссное решение. Умеет больше, чем просто `dd`.

Comment: Почему? Из моего опыта Rufus часто портит образы. Правда что с записью windows справляется идеально